# How to display data in a given time range in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, time

Sort films by number of comments

```
topMovie = Movie.objects.annotate(
            num_comments=Count('Comments')).order_by('-num_comments')
```

model.py:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Year = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    Rated = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    movie_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Comments')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(blank =True,default = now)
```

how to transfer the time frame to display this field

```
topMovie = Movie.objects.annotate(
            num_comments=Count('Comments')).order_by('-num_comments')
```

within the specified time frames

Comment: What are the specified time frames?

Comment: specified time frames provide in body of GET request 'startdate' and 'enddate' in format '25112020'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the comments with:

```
topMovie = Movie.objects.filter(
    Comments__pub_date__range=(start_timestamp, end_timestamp)
).annotate(
    num_comments=Count('Comments')
).order_by('-num_comments')
```

This will not contain any m`topMovies` without `Comment`s in the given window. You can use [**`filter=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter) to also retrieve `Movie`s with `Comment`s outside the range:

```
from django.db.models import Q

topMovie = Movie.objects.annotate(
    num_comments=Count(
        'Comments',
        filter=Q(Comments__pub_date__range=(start_timestamp, end_timestamp))
    )
).order_by('-num_comments')
```

Comment: thanks , but doesn't sorting  . In database I have pub_date  in format "2020-11-22T20:07:55+01:00"

Comment: @tarp20: but you are talking about *filtering* not *sorting*. You of course need to replace `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` with the ones that you use for filtering.

Comment: figured out thank you ))if you have time and desire, please take a Look my one more issue, maybe you will be interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955569/how-best-to-implement-the-logic-for-determining-the-post-rank-in-serializer